# Touch Event is Not Working? in UImageview?

Tags: iphone

i have done following in viewdidload of viewcontroller.m

```
    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
img.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:img];
[img release];
```

but Touchbegan , touch Moved ,everything is not working ,when i check through Break Point?
instead of this,when i use XIB file,i set multipleTouchEnabled ,but in both
touch event is not working...anyHelp? please?

Answer (score 3):

You should try setting this property:

```
img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

But this is not enough,
because the methods:

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
```

are from the UIResponder class (the base class of UIVIew) and not the UIViewController.

So if you want them to be called, you have to define a sub class of a UIView (or UIImageView in your case) where you override the base methods.

Example:

**MyImageView.h**:

```
@interface MyImageView : UIImageView {
}

@end
```

**MyImageView.m**:

```
@implementation MyImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:rect]) {
        // We set it here directly for convenience
        // As by default for a UIImageView it is set to NO
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Do what you want here
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan!");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Do what you want here
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded!");
}

@end
```

Then you can instantiate a MyImageView in your example with the view controller:

```
img = [[MyImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:img];
[img release];
```

And you should see the touch events (also assuming self.view has userInteractionEnabled set to YES of course).

Comment: One correction, UIViewCOntroller ALSO inherits from UIResponder. If you flip the userInteractionEnabled flag of UIImageView, then it becomes part of the responder chain. And, if you don't handle the touch events in the UIImageView subclass (which you don't have to), the WILL be forwarded up the chain and eventually reach the UIViewController subclass managing the view hierarchy.